# PyQt5 error: TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.9

My goal is to make a web browser in PyQt5 and this is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://www.google.com'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showMaximized()
        navbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(navbar)

        back_btn = QAction('<=', self)
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        navbar.addAction(back_btn)

        forward_btn = QAction('=>', self)
        forward_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navbar.addAction(forward_btn)
        reload_btn = QAction('reload', self)
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navbar.addAction(reload_btn)

        self.url_bar = QLineEdit(self)
        navbar.addAction(self.url_bar)


APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('Kahari Go Web')
window = MainWindow()
APP.exec_()
```

but When I run my code I always get a error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\kahari Go Web\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "D:\kahari Go Web\main.py", line 29, in __init__
    navbar.addAction(self.url_bar)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  addAction(self, QAction): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QLineEdit'
  addAction(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QLineEdit'
  addAction(self, QIcon, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QLineEdit'
  addAction(self, str, PYQT_SLOT): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QLineEdit'
  addAction(self, QIcon, str, PYQT_SLOT): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QLineEdit'
```

the only thing that I try is to go through all the articles but I cannot understand it so I run it in repl.it but repl.it cannot import PyQt5.
I am using python 3.9 32-bit in windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addAction()` is used to add a `QAction` and not a widget, if you want to add the QLineEdit then you must use `addWidget()`:

```py
navbar.addWidget(self.url_bar)
```

Comment: Thank you very much eyllanesc!